# Cisco ASA: Prevent any single internal host from saturating bandwidth of outside Internet interface

Tags: bandwidth, cisco-asa, throttling

We have an ASA 5510 at the edge of our network connected to a 10Mb Internet pipe. All internal IPs are private so we have external and internal interfaces. I'd like to prevent any single internal host from consuming more than 75% bandwidth on the outside interface. I realize that this would only help under specific combinations of usage by hosts, but it will meet our needs for now.

Is the ASA 5510 capable of this kind of throttling?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its the quality of service policies that you can place on the device.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_tech_note09186a008084de0c.shtml